# How to install Django with pip inside a virtualenv in /var/www/html/project_name folder?

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, pip, virtualenv

I'm using Ubuntu 15.04 with Python 2.7, pip 1.5.6 and virtualenv 1.11.6.

I will create a Django project inside `/var/www/html/project_name` (and work in that directory) for use it with Apache2.

I created a virtual environment named venv inside the project_name folder for syncing purposes.

With the virtual environment activated, I just cant't run `pip install django` because I get 'Permission denied' message. So I try the command `sudo pip install django`, but that will install Django globally.

So, running `which pip`, I get `/var/www/html/project_name/venv/bin/pip`.

But running `sudo which pip`, I get `/usr/bin/pip`.

Does someone get any idea about how it is possible to install Django (or any other package) inside the virtual environment?

PS: I know it's possible to run `sudo venv/bin/pip install django`, but it doesn't seem very useful.

Comment: Why don't you just give yourself write permissions for /var/www/html/project_name/venv/?

Comment: [Install pip in your system, not virtual env](http://askubuntu.com/questions/629686/python-pip-package-not-found-on-ubuntu-15-04-running-as-live-usb) and run it with `pip install django`

Comment: You should **not** put either Django or your project inside /var/www.

Comment: @DanielRoseman why not? my virtualenvs and projects always live there

Comment: @DanielRoseman I would revise that a tad by saying not within one of the html directories under /var/www. If it's a script directory (i.e. something not under one of the document roots) then it's fine.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, I have the same doubt as doniyor. Why not?

Comment: Because code does not belong in the Apache documentroot. It increases the chance of a misconfiguration allowing Apache to serve the code itself, potentially exposing your business logic and database credentials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your trouble is presumably that you don't have write access to this `/var/www/html/project_name` directory. Your choices are:

1. Change the permissions, recursively, so that you do have permissions to write to that directory.
2. Run the following commands:

.

```
$ sudo su
# . venv/bin/activate
# pip install
```

Just to add what everyone's been saying and I sort of skimmed over: NEVER EVER put sensitive things (that includes your django project) under the document root. You can store it under something like `/var/www/scripts` or something, but don't put it under the document root.

Another way of deploying is using something like gunicorn as the "main" webserver and then just having whatever world visible webserver (like apache) reverse proxy to gunicorn. I've done this with nginx and it's fairly easy to setup, the only down side is then you have to setup something extra in your system's init scripts to start up gunicorn.

Comment: While this should work, you may want to consider creating a service user to deploy your project. While this is a larger topic, it is worth looking into. I develop my Django projects in my home directory (virtualenvs and all). When I deploy, I have a process to deploy to /var/www/html/project_name under the same user as Apache from the git production branch, do a pip install of the requirements file, collect static files, etc. Do *not* put your entire Django project under /var/www/html - that is world readable, and could result in things like settings file (w/ the secret key) becoming readable.